# Getting Mutual Facebook Friends iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

is there any way I can get friends of friends with a FBRequest or something like it? Right now I can only retrieve a users friends, but I want to retrieve my user's mutual friends. I realize that this won't work for all users, since of privacy permissions, but there should be at least a few users who have their profiles set to everyone. Could anyone move me in the right direction? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Social Context API to get mutual friends: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user.context/mutual_friends

It will only returns mutual friends that are using the app and a total count